# Removing ALL characters with Command+Delete when renaming a file/folder removes/trashes the file/folder entirely

Tags: filesystem, folders, macos

Reproducible steps:

- Open a Finder window (either via an 'open/upload file' in another application or directly)
- select a folder with one click
- hit 'Enter' to change the name
- Use 'Command+Delete' to remove the entire line of text
- The folder will be removed completely

Is there a way to prevent the removal of the file/folder from happening when trying to rename a file/folder?

I am OK with removing/preventing the shortcut to delete files altogether anywhere in the OS.

I'm running Yosemite, but also exists in El Capitan and likely before as well.

Comment: But command+delete is a shortcut to move files/folders to Trash. Why not simply pressing delete without command?

Comment: Because Command+delete is also a shortcut to remove text all the way to the beginning of the line.   The issue is that I use this shortcut WAY more often than deleting.   Since I am in a 'Text' mode, I feel it's scope should have precedent.  I am OK with removing the shortcut to delete files altogether.

Comment: That's strange, ⌘+⌫ clears file name to the beginnig of the line instead of moving it to Trash for me.

Comment: ⌘+⌫ is 'delete to beginning' **if** & only if, the cursor is 'solo' i.e. there is no text selection. If you simply hit Enter to edit a file title, everything is pre-selected & ⌘+⌫ is then Trash. If the name is pre-selected, then you only need to start typing to rename, so 'delete' of any kind is just a nervous tic, not a requirement.